# Try to choose a special number $t$ which satisify $\eta(f(x))=f(t)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$\eta : \mathbb{R}[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a ring homomorphism with  $\eta(1)=1$. Prove there exist $ t \in\mathbb{R}$ s.t.$\eta(f(x))=f(t)$ for all $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]$.

My idea:

$\eta$ is surjective, then there exist a $g(x)$ s.t. $\mathbb{R}[x]/\left\langle g(x)\right\rangle $ is isomorphism to $ \mathbb{R}$. But what can I do next, find the root of $g(x)$? It may not a real number. Could someone give me some details, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Show that the only ring homomorphism $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is the identity map (this is necessary, in general if we would consider arbitrary rings $S$ and homomorphisms $S[x]\to S$ we would need the extra hypothesis that $\eta$ is a morphism of $S$-algebras) . Then let $t:=\eta(x)$ and show that this $t$ satisfies the required property.
(Here I assumed that ring homomorphisms preserve the unit, but the claim is wrong anyways if we wouldn't require that)

Comment: Thanks for your comment